prove the closedness of Differential Operator
Let $E=\mathbb{C}[0,1]$ be the normed space with the norm given by $\|x\|=\displaystyle\max_{t\in [0,1]}|x(t)|$ and
$f: D_f \longrightarrow E$,
$x(t) \longmapsto x'(t)$
where the prime denotes differentiation and $D_f \subset E$ is the subspace of functions having continuous derivative. Then, $f$ is closed.
This is what my professor did
Assume that $x_n\in D_f$ such that $x_n \rightarrow x$ and $f(x_n)=(x'_n)\rightarrow y.$
We need to show that $x\in D_f$ and $f(x)=y$.
Since convergence in the norm of $\mathbb{C}[0,1]$ is uniform on $[0,1]$, from $x'_n \rightarrow y$, we have:
$\displaystyle\int\limits_{0}^{t} y(\tau)d(\tau)=\displaystyle\int\limits_{0}^{t} \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x'_n(\tau)d(\tau)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\displaystyle\int\limits_{0}^{t} x'_n(\tau)d(\tau)=x(t)-x(0)$,  
that means, $x(t)=x(0)+\displaystyle\int\limits_{0}^{t} y(\tau)d(\tau)$.
This implies that $x\in D_f$ and $f(x)=y$. So, $f$ is closed.
i want to ask y'all what is "$\tau$" in $d(\tau)$ here?

Variable of integration is  a dummy variable. How does it matter as  to what symbol you use for it?
